# Which do I use: 喜欢不喜欢 or 喜不喜欢?

Tags: grammar, difference, sentence-structure

I know that 喜不喜欢 and 喜欢不喜欢 have the same meaning, but in a sentence, which would look more appealing or make more sense in the sentence? In other words, which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Both are grammatical and meanings are identical. I would say which one to use is a completely prosody thing.

Comment: what is prosody?

Comment: Prosody is the 'sound and feel' of the sentence, like choosing between "A's B" and "B of A" in English in a context where they mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chinese speakers like 4-beat rythm better, so you should be using 喜不喜欢 most of the time.

Answer (score 6):

The **A不AB** and **AB不AB** pattern that widely used in Chinese,  and **A不AB** is sort of just a shorten expression of **AB不AB**, **AB** should be *verb.* or *adj.*. it means : Will you or not do something(when AB is *verb.*) or Are you or not AB(when AB is *adj.*).

喜欢

变态

讨厌

公平

优秀

Answer (score 4):

In China I hear far more commonly 喜不喜欢.

Typically if you have a two character word with that construction, you would use it like this:

喜不喜欢

过不过分

便不便宜

Answer (score 4):

I am a native Chinese speaker, so I'd like to answer your question here.

actually, they are both rightly used as 喜不喜欢 or 喜欢不喜欢。But in daily life, people prefer to use the simpler one, namely 喜不喜欢， and it sound more orally, while 喜欢不喜欢 sounds more normal.

They are similar to the usage of "好不好看vs好看不好看"，“漂不漂亮vs漂亮不漂亮”.But if you want sound more native, choose the former ones.

Answer (score -8):

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) helped me with this answer.

Like the comment above, 喜不喜欢 and  喜欢不喜欢 are the exact same. For example:

Literally Translated into English:

**"*Do you like beer?*"**    <========== Can be translated with both.

你喜不喜欢啤酒? Do you like beer?
你喜欢不喜欢啤酒? Did you like beer?

*For some reason the second one was inputting "**did you like beer?**",but that's how Google is*.

Comment: To rely on Google Translate is rather unprofessional. E.g. 'Bring your own beer!' will get you: '把自己的啤酒！' which is un obviously ungrammatical.

Comment: Seriously, professionals *use* Google translate but no one should *rely* on it.  And this answer adds nothing to what Google translate says.

Comment: but that's how Google is --> which is why you shouldn't cite it as a source of authority in the first place